# Swift compactMap includes nil value

Tags: ios, swift

Consider the following:

```
let numbers: [String?] = ["1", "two", nil]
let intArray: [Int?] = numbers.compactMap {Int($0 ?? "0")}
print(intArray)
```

The result printed is `[Optional(1), nil, Optional(0)]`, why does it include the `nil` value? I thought these would be filtered out because of `compactMap`.

Interestingly `let intArray: [Int] = numbers.compactMap {Int($0 ?? "0")}` works without an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good example why explicit type annotation makes things sometimes worse.

According to the definition `compactMap` returns a **non-optional** array.

Without type annotation

```
let intArray = numbers.compactMap {Int($0 ?? "0")}
```

or with the correct type annotation

```
let intArray : [Int] = numbers.compactMap {Int($0 ?? "0")}
```

the result is

```
[1, 0]
```

- `"1"` is mapped to `1`
- `"two"` is ignored
- `nil` is nil-coalesced to `"0"` and mapped to `0`

---

With the bad/wrong type annotation `[Int?]` the following happens

- `"1"` is mapped to `Optional(1)`
- `"two"` cannot be converted to `Int` so instead of ignoring the value `nil` is returned
- `nil` is nil-coalesced to `"0"` and mapped to `Optional(0)`

Comment: Thanks for this. So it would seem there is no real logic to why it does this. Non-optional values become optional and nil is not filtered out.

Comment: No, the logic is pretty clear. By forcing the compiler to return an optional type **you** allowed `compactMap` to return `nil` rather than filtering the `nil` occurrences. Just don't do these *illogical* things .